# Sets Probability Calculation

Tags: probability, self-study, sample, mathematical-statistics

Working through some probability theory sample questions from my course notes and I'm having difficulty trying to prove this probability theorem:

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots$, $A_n$ be events in the sample space $\Omega$ with probability measure *P*. Show that:

*P*($A_1\bigcap$ $A_2\bigcap\ldots\bigcap$ $A_n$) $\ge$ *P*( $A_1$) + *P*( $A_2$) + $\ldots$ + *P*( $A_n$) - (*n* - 1)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Even a hint as to where to start. I'd like to figure it out on my own, so that I can understand it in full detail, but I am really stuck atm.

Comment: I think this is right - if the RHS is negative then the lower bound is trivial, but if each event has probability 1, then this gives the correct lower bound of 1.  I would look up De Morgan's law and the [inclusion exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 3):

Prove it by induction. Prove $P(A_1 \cap A_2) \geq P(A_1) + P(A_2) - 1$.
Then show
$$P(B_n) \geq \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) - (n-1) 
\implies P(B_{n+1}) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} P(A_k) - n$$
where $B_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k$.